# Installation challenge: UEFI only cannot boot from external device 32 bit cpu HELP!

Tags: system-installation, uefi

Preramble:
I got this very cheap ($79) Windows 10 computer because I'll be travelling and don't want to worry about losing it.  For previous travels I developed a script to capture my GPS log and pictures and made a blog page with map from them.  That computer is heavy and sickly.

The Ematic EWT8268K has a **hobbled UEFI** which does not allow booting from an external device (no EFI mount command). The CPU is Intel Atom Z373SG. 1GB RAM  The SSD is 32GB and I can put in a 32GB microSD

What is the very manual process for putting Ubuntu on the microSD?  I can modify the existing boot manager.  There is some incantation to which I am not privy.  Can someone help with this challenge?

OSD